# Inheriting DBModels and UI Models from Domain Models

Tags: object-oriented, architecture

I made a pretty simple CRUD API to store customers and some related information in a database.
My customer has 20 properties like Name, Telephone etc. that are all stored in an anemic domain model.
My application has a core assembly where my domain logic is located. There I have a business model, looking pretty much like this:

```
public class Customer 
{
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
   public string Telephone {get; set;}
   //Further 20 properties
}
```

I also have an assembly for my current database. I need another model there for my customer, having the same 20 properties, plus some db-related things, to archive persistence.
I also have an adapter for my UI (currently just a .NET Core API) and this adapter also needs a UI-model, having the same 20 properties.

To not repeat all 20 properties in each layer, I made my life simple and just inherited my db models and ui models from the domain models.
The example of the customer looks like that:

[image]

My UI adapter and DB adapters have dependencies on the domain model, but the domain model has no dependencies at all.
In this way I am not hurting any principle I learned over the last years, but for some reason I have a strange feeling doing so.

Is my approach okay, or do you have any ideas why I am doing the wrong thing?

Comment: "Okay" in what sense? A lot of things there I would consider an anti-pattern in itself, like: Making a CRUD API, having an anemic domain model, inheriting properties, having UI and DB separated completely. I would consider the above not a good architecture at all, but then again, there is no objective metric to measure against.

Comment: About anemic domain model I read a lot discussions... in my simple case I did not see any drawbacks. But what is wrong about "CRUD API", inheritance, UI and DB seperation? I never heard that those are anti patterns? Can you recommend any articles I could read, to understand your feedback?

Comment: I've felt this exact pain/temptation myself. @DavidElsner does your language support mixins? Really you just want to not repeat yourself in terms of the model property names, I don't think you want 'real' inheritance. Also, consider just repeating the properties and using something like AutoMapper to avoid writing all the manual property-copying code from one model to another.

Comment: @graham I'm using C#. Last time i had this problem I used t4 Templates to generate my models..but this was also causing problems... I'm already afraid I need inheritance even though its not ,,real" in my case... :( I also don't understand why theres no general pattern for this case... Isn't almost every second crud application facing this problem?

Comment: @DavidElsner I use C# as well and sort of agree with you. Interesting.

Comment: But I am still confused about Robert Bräutigams comment. What's bad with the things he criticized? Like crud api, separate db and UI etc...? Should I rethink another part of my design?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a big fan of the mantra "composition over inheritance", but this is a case where I am going to recommend it.

By using inheritance, you are effectively saying that every place in the code that consumes a `CustomerBusinessModel`, I can pass in either a `CustomerViewModel`, `CostomerSubmitModel` or `CustomerDBModel` and nobody will care. That message is probably not true.

I fully understand that you don't want to replicate all those properties of `CustomerBusinessModel`, but that can be achieved equally well with composition, where each of `CustomerViewModel`, `CustomerSubmitModel` and `CustomerDBModel` holds a reference to a `CustomerBusinessModel`.

If this means you would have to create a lot of forwarding getters and setters, then you have found a function that lives in the wrong class and should be moved to the corresponding `Customer*Model` class.

Comment: I also thought about this idea... but this changes the structure of my models to "nested models". In this way my NoSQL db holds records that are nested but should not be nested. Also people posting to my api have to nest some contents of the model with no reason... this drawback kept me from doing this...

Answer (score 0):

The reason for having different DTOs in layers, such as persistence entities, domain models, view models, ... is the **decouple** the code by making sure each layer works with its own data structure that's built to the purpose that it (internally) needs it to be.

By having these inherit from one another, you are inherently defeating that purpose. Don't do it.

> To not repeat all 20 properties in each layer, I made my life simple and just inherited my db models and ui models from the domain models.

First of all, it takes literally 5 seconds to copy/paste them once. You're not saving any significant amount of time. Given the same property name/type (as would inherently be the case if you're using inheritance now), Automapper essentially maps them for you without requiring any active mapping configuration for these DTOs.

But the compromise in architectural integrity you're causing because of this will be measured in **days if not weeks** worth of time to fix in the future.

Secondly, the main issue here is that **just because two things are structurally the same, does not mean that they (or their similarities) are actually the same thing**.

Reducing copy/paste by creating shared logic is only applicable when the duplicate instances share the same lifecycle, i.e. changing one inherently means changing the other.

While you may have DTOs in several layers that happen to have some similar properties; do those DTOs share an actual life cycle? No. Just because one of them changes doesn't mean that the others *must* invariably change.

This principle is practically the core tenet of OOP. Classes exist because they have a responsibility, and as clean code dictates each class should have only one responsibility. Two responsibilities therefore need to be represented by two classes.

**This remains correct even if these classes happen to be structurally equal to one another.**

It may appear like you have semantically skirted this advice by technically having two classes (but in an inheritance structure), but the problem remains the same: the base class is representing multiple completely separate (though structurally similar) responsibilities, which the derived classes extend instead of defining their own.

A domain object, data entity and (public) DTO could all have the exact same set of properties, but they each have their own unique purpose, and they should therefore not be lumped into a single class.

When trying to refactor code, you have to **distinguish correlation from coincidence**. If you spot a similarity, and there is a correlation here (e.g. if one changes, the other must invariably change too), then there's reason to consider abstraction.

But if it is coincidence, i.e. they are completely unrelated except that they happen to look the same, each for their own reasons, then abstraction would actually be introducing problems instead of solving them.

Implementing inheritance here brings significantly more problems to the table than it solves. What you gain is utterly negligible (mere seconds), what you lose is a significant impact on the long term maintainability of your codebase. If there is *ever* a reason for one of these DTOs to change without the other (and no, you can't tell the future), your shortcut is going to end up costing you so much more time than it ever saved you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, IMHO, anaemic domain model and layered app structure, where you have db layer, then service layer and presenter is not really OOP-design, even though many call it OOP. Such kind of structure forces us to use more procedural style rather than OOP. It works fine if it's a small project, but becomes a mess the more we grow our code base. But that's more topic for holly wars. Besides such kind of architecture is very common these days, so we have to deal with it. And of course there are no right and wrong things, and everything comes to the point how much effort you put and how much profit you get from it.

In your case, I would have different DTOs for different layers, and use mappers to convert one to another. Idk about C# but there should some libs which allow you to implement mappers without a lot of hassle. I personally dislike inheritance, it seems appealing at the first glance, but it's  a pain to maintain the code where inheritance is widely used. Having different DTO's allows you to separate layers, even thought it seems stupid to have a bunch of similar objects and mappers, but it makes architecture cleaner. Plus it's not always the same what you show to the user and what you have in DB.

Also I would say having an entity with 20 fields is already a sign that there are some potential issues in your data model. I know, pretty often we have to deal with predefined DB structure, but table with 20 columns most likely is not normalised and can be decomposed into smaller parts.